# How to play RTSP live streaming link in HTML

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, rtsp, live-streaming

How to play RTSP live streaming url in my phonegap application.

Currently i'm using this - but it's not working fine with my link. https://github.com/SpecForge/html5_rtsp_player/blob/master/README.md

Help me out.
Thanks....

Comment: "relies on server-side websocket proxy for retransmitting RTSP streams to browser" did you do this part?

Answer (score 0):

Install ws-rtsp-proxy on one of the machines and set the websocket.url property to the machine that has the proxy server installed.